# How to set schema parameter in osm2pgsql calling

Tags: postgis, postgresql, openstreetmap, osm2pgsql

How I can to set schema name parameter when call `osm2pgsql`?
For example:

```
osm2pgsql --create -s -C 2500 -G  -S D:\default.style -d osm_db -o input -U osm_user -W -H localhost -r pbf D:\osm.pbf
```

I set the `-o` parameter but information was loaded in `public`...
How do I set a target schema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting a different target schema is currently not supported by osm2pgsql. See this GitHub issue for details: https://github.com/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql/issues/768

Comment: There is old issue and result is hasn't existed((  Thanx for information